# case insensitive for jTree

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtree

I am kinda new in java because I mainly study autoIt language. I am trying to learn `JTree` and `Action Listener`. I have this code(actually came from internet: sorry I forgot the link.) which have a jTree sample and filtering for the search functionality. I tweaked a bit of the code so that I can understand it on my own. The code works perfectly fine. Tho, when I search, I need to input the exact word to be able to see the result. How can I make the search words case-insensitive(or I don't know what its called) to be able to search properly even if I did not input the exact word. I searched about `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` methods but I don't know how to implement it. Thanks in advance :D

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public final class FilteredJTreeExample {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
          }
      });
    }
     private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("I DONT KNOW IF THIS WILL WORK, BUT WHATEVER MAN!!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JTree tree = createTree(pane);
        JTextField filter = createFilterField(pane);

        filter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(createDocumentListener(tree, filter));
    }

    private static JTree createTree(final Container pane) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("JTree");
        FilteredTreeModel model = new FilteredTreeModel(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
        JTree tree = new JTree(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(scrollPane, c);
        createTreeNodes(root);
        expandTree(tree);

        return tree;
    }

    private static JTextField createFilterField(final Container pane) {
        JTextField filter = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(filter, c);

        return filter;
    }

    private static DocumentListener createDocumentListener(final JTree tree, final JTextField filter) {
        return new DocumentListener() {

          @Override
          public void insertUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
            applyFilter();
          }

          @Override
          public void removeUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
            applyFilter();
          }

          @Override
          public void changedUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
            applyFilter();
          }

          public void applyFilter() {
            FilteredTreeModel filteredModel = (FilteredTreeModel) tree.getModel();
            filteredModel.setFilter(filter.getText());

            DefaultTreeModel treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) filteredModel.getTreeModel();
            treeModel.reload();

            expandTree(tree);
          }
      };
    }

    private static void expandTree(final JTree tree) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
          tree.expandRow(i);
        }
    }

    private static void createTreeNodes(final DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode ojt1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("BOYSSS");
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Rey"));
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Regi"));
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Geo"));
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jerome"));
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Ryan"));
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Leo"));
        ojt1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Ricardo"));
        node.add(ojt1);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode ojt2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("GIRLSS");
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Neri"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Chesca"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Diane"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Faye"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Mimi"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Shea"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Shane"));
        ojt2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Lorraine"));
        node.add(ojt2);
  }
}
```

ohh btw, this is the `FilteredTreeModel` class:

```
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public final class FilteredTreeModel implements TreeModel {

  private TreeModel treeModel;
  private String filter;

  public FilteredTreeModel(final TreeModel treeModel) {
    this.treeModel = treeModel;
    this.filter = "";
  }

  public TreeModel getTreeModel() {
    return treeModel;
  }

  public void setFilter(final String filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
  }

  private boolean recursiveMatch(final Object node, final String filter) {

    boolean matches = node.toString().contains(filter);

    int childCount = treeModel.getChildCount(node);
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      Object child = treeModel.getChild(node, i);
      matches |= recursiveMatch(child, filter);
    }

    return matches;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getRoot() {
    return treeModel.getRoot();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getChild(final Object parent, final int index) {
    int count = 0;
    int childCount = treeModel.getChildCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      Object child = treeModel.getChild(parent, i);
      if (recursiveMatch(child, filter)) {
        if (count == index) {
          return child;
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildCount(final Object parent) {
    int count = 0;
    int childCount = treeModel.getChildCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      Object child = treeModel.getChild(parent, i);
      if (recursiveMatch(child, filter)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLeaf(final Object node) {
    return treeModel.isLeaf(node);
  }

  @Override
  public void valueForPathChanged(final TreePath path, final Object newValue) {
    treeModel.valueForPathChanged(path, newValue);
  }

  @Override
  public int getIndexOfChild(final Object parent, final Object childToFind) {
    int childCount = treeModel.getChildCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      Object child = treeModel.getChild(parent, i);
      if (recursiveMatch(child, filter)) {
        if (childToFind.equals(child)) {
          return i;
        }
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public void addTreeModelListener(final TreeModelListener l) {
    treeModel.addTreeModelListener(l);
  }

  @Override
  public void removeTreeModelListener(final TreeModelListener l) {
    treeModel.removeTreeModelListener(l);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps try: `boolean matches = node.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());`. You may also want to have the **recursiveMatch()** method have an optional boolean parameter where you can either ignore letter case or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the lowercase/uppercase idea.

Try this: `boolean matches = node.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase())`

Instead of: `boolean matches = node.toString().contains(filter);`

Note how we use `.toLowerCase()` on both strings that we want to match.